# React `StrictMode` does not allow message exchange between worker and React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, web-worker

I am currently developing an application using webpack5 and React18.

I created the following code to exchange messages with webworker and React component which uses monaco-editor.

I expected app runs like following.

- When button clicked, onSubmit() fires and send value to worker.
- Worker get message with value, bundle it and send bundledCode back.

```
// React component
import React, { useState, useRef, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
import MonacoEditor from './Monaco/MonacoEditor';
import type { iMessageBundleWorker } from "../worker/types";

const MonacoContainer = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
    const bundleWorker = useMemo(
        () => new Worker(new URL('/src/worker/bundle.worker.ts', import.meta.url), { type: "module" }
        ), []
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if(window.Worker) {
            bundleWorker.addEventListener('message', _cbBundledMessage, false);
        }

        return () => {
            _onUnmount();
        }
    }, []);

    const _onUnmount = () => {
        bundleWorker && bundleWorker.removeEventListener('message', _cbBundledMessage, false);
        bundleWorker && bundleWorker.terminate();
    };


    const _onSubmit = () => {

        console.log("Send code to worker");

        bundleWorker.postMessage({
            order: "bundle",
            code: value
        });
    };

    const _cbBundledMessage = (e: MessageEvent<iMessageBundleWorker>) => {
        bundledCode && console.log(bundledCode);
    };

    return (
        <div className="monaco-container">
            <MonacoEditor
              {/*...*/}
            />
            <button onClick={_onSubmit}>submit</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

```
// worker
const bundler = (code: string) => {
    // bundle code and return it.
};

self.addEventListener('message', (e:MessageEvent<iMessageBundleWorker>): void => {

    const { order, code } = e.data;


    console.log("[bundle.worker.ts] got message");

    if(order !== "bundle") return;

    console.log("[bundle.worker.ts] start bundle process...");

    if(code) {
        bundler(code)
        .then((result: iBuildResult) => {
            self.postMessage({
                bundledCode: result.code,
                err: null
            });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            // handle error
        });
    }
}, false);


console.log("[bundle.worker] running...");
```

```
// parent component
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <React.StrictMode>
                <MonacoContainer />
            </React.StrictMode>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I run it, I can see that no messages are being exchanged.

However, if I remove `StrictMode`, it immediately exchanges message without problems.

But with `StrictMode`, it won't.

##### Here is what I have surveyed to solve.

- `StrictMode` causes `useEffect()` to be ran twice, so maybe not cleaning up properly has something to do with this problem?

Both `worker.terminate()` and `worker.removeEventListener('message')` are executed during cleanup.

- Is it because they have different origins?

Development is done locally, and I have confirmed that both are `http://localhost:8080`.
So it should not be cross-origin.

- You think I am missing the message because the React component and the worker have different timing for completion of mounting.

I don't think that is related to `StrictMode`, as it does not occur when app runs without `StrictMode`.

So I'm stuck.

Is there any limitation to communicate with a worker in React18 that cannot be done in development mode?

I am developing in `Strictmode` with React18, webpack5, but I wonder if there is any way to exchange messages with the worker without any problems.

My environment and settings.

Node.js version 16

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["dom", "WebWorker", "es5", "es2015.collection", "es2015.promise"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackahePlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'producton';

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.tsx',
        'bundle.worker': './src/worker/bundle.worker.ts',

        // monaco-editor requirement:
        'editor.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js',
        'json.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker',
        'css.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker',
        'html.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker',
        'ts.worker': 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.*', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.ts'],
      },
    output: {
        globalObject: 'self',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-react'],
                            plugins: [isDevelopment && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')].filter(Boolean)
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.ttf$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackahePlugin({
            title: 'Output Management',
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),
        isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin()
    ].filter(Boolean),
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: './dist',
        hot: true,
        port: 8080,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single'
    }
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Strict mode causes your component to render twice and run effects twice in development.This is useful because it will demonstrate undesirable behaviours when the component it torn down. That your component misbehaves under these circumstances suggests that something is wrong with your component. https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode

Comment: Indeed, the OP is terminating the worker on unmount. It's gone after the first effect cleanup (I'm guessing `terminate` does something a little more permanent than removeEventListener)

Comment: It was caused by `useMemo()`.

This is strictly speculative.

In other words, it seems that useMemo() was keeping the terminated worker over component remounts, so it kept referring to the terminated worker after remounting, and therefore could not send the message because it is already aborted.

So I decided to stop using useMemo() to hold the worker instance and instead hold it as a class field, which solved everything.

Whether or not this is a better approach, there does not seem to be a way to interact with the worker in the function component.

Thank you.